# Move button panel above on-screen keyboard

Tags: basic4android

While adding a contact, when the on-screen keyboard is displayed the panel containing the 'Done' and 'Revert' buttons scrolls up above the on-screen keyboard.

How is this achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can force the screen to scroll up by modifying the manifest file. See this [link](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/bugs-wishlist/12136-keyboard-appears-top-edit-text.html#post67947).

Comment: I saw that page. The EditText fields are shown OK and the screen does scroll up so they are never obscured by the keyboard. I was just curious as to how they managed to get the button panel to move up above the keyboard in certain apps.

Comment: I see. I don't know whether it is possible.